# How do I parse this supposedly JSON format

Tags: json

I have a huge file with data in the below format. (It's the response from an API call I made to one of Twitter's APIs). I want to extract the value of the field "followers_count" from it. Ordinarily, I would do this with jq with the following command : cat  | jq -r '.followers_count'

But this contains special characters so jq cannot handle it. Can someone help by telling me how do I convert it in JSON (e.g. using a shell script) or alternatively how to get the followers_count field without conversion? If this format has a specific name, I would be interested to know about it.
Thanks.

SAMPLE LINE IN FILE:

b'[{"id":2361407554,"id_str":"2361407554","name":"hakimo ait","screen_name":"hakimo_ait","location":"","description":"","url":null,"entities":{"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":0,"friends_count":6,"listed_count":0,"created_at":"Sun Feb 23 19:08:04 +0000 2014","favourites_count":0,"utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"verified":false,"statuses_count":1,"lang":"fr","status":{"created_at":"Sun Feb 23 19:09:21 +0000 2014","id":437665498961293312,"id_str":"437665498961293312","text":"c.ronaldo","truncated":false,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[],"urls":[]},"source":"\u003ca href=\"https:\/\/mobile.twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eMobile Web (M2)\u003c\/a\u003e","in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"lang":"es"},"contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/sticky\/default_profile_images\/default_profile_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/sticky\/default_profile_images\/default_profile_normal.png","profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"has_extended_profile":false,"default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":true,"following":false,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false,"translator_type":"none"}]'

Comment: Can you strip off the first two `b'` and last `'` characters and the run the value through `JSON.parse`?

Comment: It looks like you dumped a string presentation of the Python string into the file, instead of the JSON itself. The first step would be to dump the JSON into the file correctly.

Comment: @J.D.Pace: This question doesn't seem to be about JavaScript,

Comment: @FelixKling: I saw "jq" and shifted to "jquery".

Comment: @ J.D. Pace: Tried it - didn't work!

Comment: @FelixKling: jq is a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor. It's different from jquery

Comment: Where have I mentioned jQuery?

Comment: I just reread your question. You said the example you posted is a single line. As I said, you have to make sure to actually store JSON in the file. A "list" of `b'...'` items is not JSON. A valid JSON document would be a single array at the root, e.g. `[[...], [...], ...]`. If you can't do that because you are streaming to the file, then you have to select a single line **before** you pass that to jq. I don't think the problem is special characters, it's that what you are feeding to jq is not valid JSON. This is as much info as you can get since you don't show how you write to this file.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the valid JSON, if you want to grab some certain part from this response, you can dump this result in file and then iterate over it and get the text you want to grab.
otherwise, if response will be in JSON, it will be easily parse through jq library, you can also dump this record in file, convert it into json and then parse it ! 
there are multiple ways 'grep,awk,sed' ..... you can go for it !

remove 'b from beginning and ' from bottom,it will become valid JSON !

Comment: I have tried that already. Removing c'[ from the beginning and single quotes at the end - the output cannot be parsed by jq due to special characters present in the file, even though it may be a JSON representation technically.

Answer (score 0):

Well i have removed the b' from beginning and ' from the bottom ! and look it is a valid JSON, now we can easily use jq with it like this !
i am doing it with my file....

```
jq -r '.accounts|keys[]' ../saadaccounts.json | while read key ; 
do
   DATA="$(jq ".accounts       [$key]" ../saadaccounts.json )"
   FNAME=$( echo $DATA  | jq -r '.first_name' )
   LNAME=$( echo $DATA  | jq -r '.Last_name'  )
done

*** YOUR JSON FILE *** 

[  
 {
  "id":2361393867,
  "id_str":"2361393867",
  "name":"graam a7bab",
  "screen_name":"bedoo691",
  "location":"",
  "description":"\u0627\u0633\u062a\u063a\u0641\u0631\u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0648\u0627\u062a\u0648\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u064a\u0647\u0647 ..!*",
  "url":null,
  "entities":{
     "description":{
        "urls":[

        ]
     }
  },
  "protected":false,
  "followers_count":1,
  "friends_count":6,
  "listed_count":0,
  "created_at":"Sun Feb 23 19:03:21 +0000 2014",
  "favourites_count":1,
  "utc_offset":null,
  "time_zone":null,
  "geo_enabled":false,
  "verified":false,
  "statuses_count":7,
  "lang":"ar",
  "status":{
     "created_at":"Tue Mar 04 16:07:44 +0000 2014",
     "id":440881284383256576,
     "id_str":"440881284383256576",
     "text":"@Naif8989",
     "truncated":false,
     "entities":{
        "hashtags":[

        ],
        "symbols":[

        ],
        "user_mentions":[
           {
              "screen_name":"Naif8989",
              "name":"\u200f naif alharbi",
              "id":540343286,
              "id_str":"540343286",
              "indices":[
                 0,
                 9
              ]
           }
        ],
        "urls":[

        ]
     },
     "source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e",
     "in_reply_to_status_id":437675858485321728,
     "in_reply_to_status_id_str":"437675858485321728",
     "in_reply_to_user_id":2361393867,
     "in_reply_to_user_id_str":"2361393867",
     "in_reply_to_screen_name":"bedoo691",
     "geo":null,
     "coordinates":null,
     "place":null,
     "contributors":null,
     "is_quote_status":false,
     "retweet_count":0,
     "favorite_count":0,
     "favorited":false,
     "retweeted":false,
     "lang":"und"
  },
  "contributors_enabled":false,
  "is_translator":false,
  "is_translation_enabled":false,
  "profile_background_color":"C0DEED",
  "profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png",
  "profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png",
  "profile_background_tile":false,
  "profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/437664693373911040\/ydODsIeh_normal.jpeg",
  "profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/437664693373911040\/ydODsIeh_normal.jpeg",
  "profile_link_color":"1DA1F2",
  "profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED",
  "profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6",
  "profile_text_color":"333333",
  "profile_use_background_image":true,
  "has_extended_profile":false,
  "default_profile":true,
  "default_profile_image":false,
  "following":false,
  "follow_request_sent":false,
  "notifications":false,
  "translator_type":"none"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I changed the sample to reflect the more trickier part of the output that jq fails at. Can you please have a look at this.